# Connect Dlink xStack DGS-3420 stack to a Brocade Stack

Tags: networking, switch, brocade, d-link

I'm currently having difficulty determining the best way to connect a Dlink DGS-3420-52T switch stack to a IBM B50G switch stack.

I have two IBM B50G switches stacked together, which then connect to our firewall and then out to the internet.

I have 5 D'Link xStack DGS-3420 series switches stacked together in a ring topology.  What is the best way to connect these 5 D'Link DGS-3420 series switches to the IBM B50G stack?

Is LACP (Link Aggregation Control Protocol) going to be my best best?

How do I spread the uplink ports across the D'Link stack?

Is trying to connect these two separate stacks together a bad idea in the first place?

Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring LACP across a IBM B50G switch stack](http://serverfault.com/questions/501939/configuring-lacp-across-a-ibm-b50g-switch-stack)

Comment: The IBM B50G seem to be Brocade switches. Page 490 of the FastIron 7.1 configuration Guide suggests this should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your only choice here is LACP, make some port channels between the switches in a way that makes sense in your topology, take consideration of the amount of traffic has to flow trough each of them and avoid creating bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.  As I understand switch stacking, the entire stack is seen as 1 large switch.  If I wanted to use LACP I would have to create a lag that spans 8-10 ports on each stack.  8-10 physical Ethernet cables between the two stacks.  Is LACP capable of aggregating 8-10 1 Gigabit cat5e cables spanned across both the Dlink stack and the IBM Stack?

Comment: That depends on the switches, I don't have the specs of them right now but it should not pose any problem

Answer (score 0):

from the [reference documentation](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Business_Products/DGS/DGS%203420/Manual/DGS_3420_Series_R150_CLI_Reference_Guide.pdf), it does not look like the D-Link switches would allow you to create LAGs spanning more than one physical switch, "physical" stacking enabled or not.

Since using just a single switch for stack interconnection would introduce a single point of failure, the route to go probably would be to use two uplinks (or uplink trunks) from the B50G / Brocade stack and make it a member in the ring like the "Chassis switch" in this picture:
[image: D-Link topology proposal]
(pic taken from the [D-Link data sheet](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Business_Products/DGS/DGS%203420/Datasheet/DGS_3420_Series_Datasheet_EU_EN.pdf))

To handle loops, either let Spanning Tree disable one of the link trunks or try to make [ERPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_Ring_Protection_Switching) work in D-Link's stacked configuration (it is claimed to be supported and would give you shorter recovery times than STP/RSTP).