# Configuring LACP across a IBM B50G switch stack

Tags: networking, ibm, switch, lacp

Is it possible to configure LACP (Link aggregation control protocol) that spans across two IBM B50G stacked switches.  Below is an illustration of what I am trying to accomplish.  I have currently configured two ports in an "active" Link aggregation group on the IBM B50G.  I have also configured the two ports on the D link DGS-3240-52T to be part of a LACP group.  However, when I connect the two Ethernet cables into the aggregated ports on both of the switches I am unable to get network connectivity.

[image: IBM B50G LACP]

Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible?

Comment: I can't seem to find the manual for the IBM switch.  But anyway, does it support Multi Link Trunking Protocol? or MLT or ?MLT.  As I understand it this feature is needed to support that scenario.  If it does it might be just a matter of enabling that.

Comment: The IBM B50G seem to be Brocade switches. Page 490 of the FastIron 7.1 configuration Guide suggests this should be no problem. …